Editing bst file to use the website name as the author
I am using the apalike.bst format for referencing, however in my thesis I need to cite some websitess that do not have an author, so I need to include the webpage name as the author, per request. For example, I want to cite the following website:
https://climateactiontracker.org/global/temperatures
On the .bib file I have the following:
@misc{noauthor_temperatures_2023,
title = {Temperatures},
url = {https://climateactiontracker.org/global/temperatures},
titleaddon = {Climate Action Tracker},
urldate = {2024},
date = {2023},
langid = {english}}

In this example no author is presented, however, the name of the organization or website needs to replace the author section. If I use the apalike.bst and "Climate Action Tracker" as the author, I would get Tracker, C.A. as a result. I need to modify the bst file to get the following:
Climate Action Tracker (2023). Temperatures. Available at: https://climateactiontracker.org/global/temperatures/ (Accessed: 2024/07/20).

you could edit the bst but easier is just to use extra brace groups, author="{{Climate Action Tracker}}" won't get abbreviated.

"Climate Action Tracker" is an example of a corporate author. As @DavidCarlisle has suggested, surround the full name with dual curly braces, to prevent BibTeX from parsing the author field as having two given names (aka first names) "Climate" and "Action" and surname (aka family name) "Tracker". In essence, writing author={{Climate Action Tracker}} tells BibTeX that the entry has an author with a three-component surname -- and no given names.
